# wso2esb DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created an API that accepts a `.xlsx` file as POST input.
Code is mentioned below:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="classroomcourse" context="/classroomcourse">
<resource methods="POST">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" scope="axis2"/>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http uri-template="http://qa-aaa.ggg.com/xyz/api/importCourses"/>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
```

When I send request via POSTMAN and attach xlsx file then I get the below error:

> [2016-03-02 17:32:13,332] ERROR -  Error while building Passthrough stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}
>   org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space be
>   tween public and system identifiers
>    at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50]
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:149)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:133)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:98)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)

Kindly guide me how can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the right message builder is enabled in the axis2.xml file, for the Content type of the ESB inbound request.

Also try removing the  `<log level="full"/>` in inSequence.

Comment: I have added following line in the axis2.xml

Comment: <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>

Comment: Error is removed but when i send file to backend service it generate the error Multipart end of file.Does WSO2ESB  4.9.0 support multipart/form-data? or how can i send multipart file via ESB 4.9.0

Comment: ASFAIK,  ESB does not support multipart, you can enable binary relay builder and formatter for the multipart/form-data.

Comment: I am going to print attached filename  received at ESB from multipart/from-data belwo is in sequence code:

Comment: <inSequence><!--<property name="filename" expression="get-    property('transport', 'filename')"/>--><property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   name="filename"
                   expression="get-property('transport', 'filename')"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="filereceivefrompostman" expression="get-property('filename')"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>

Comment: How can i print file name at ESB so i will validate the file extension.